# Where to check for orientation change in an android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app, I have a `FragmentActivity` with multiple `Fragment`s all in portrait mode except for one specific `Fragment`. I move between `Fragment`s through footer `View`s in the `FragmentActivity`.

I have a different layout (actually have the same name but different widget `View`s) for this specific `Fragment` when there is an orientation change. When in landscape mode, I want to remove specific widgets from the `Fragment` layout `View` and the footer `View` of the `FragmentActivity` and when back in portrait, add everything back.

I have saved all the data I need in `onSavedInstanceState()` in the `Fragment`, but where best should I possibly test for an orientation change so that I can restore the `View`s appropriately?

Not sure I can override `onConfigurationChange()` and test there in my `Fragment` because I don't have the **android:configChanges="orientation"** in my android `Manifest`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Keep this check in onCreate(). When you rotate your device the app is restarted. So onCreate is called again when the app restarts.

```
int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
   // Landscape
}
else {
   // Portrait  
}
```

Comment: you can create separate xmls for portrait and landscape views. create a folder named "layout-land" in your "res" folder and create an xml for your landscape view in that folder. Keep the names of both the xmls (portrait & landscape) same. Your views will be adjusted automatically. Be sure to keep all the widgets in each xml intact (just change the visibility of the widgets u dont need in either view to "GONE").

Comment: thanks so much. but actually i just realised from my comment, i meant you answer gave me other ideas.. i did not really mean it as a question but glad it happened, because i forgot about using the View visibility option. :)

Answer (score 20):

You can control the orientation change by overriding `onConfigurationChanged` function of your fragment as well.

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
           Log.v("TAG","Landscape !!!");
        }
        else { 
           Log.v("TAG","Portrait !!!");
       }
   }
```

Comment: for me it is not called

Comment: It seems to work from the Main Activity and not the fragment.

Comment: This will fire only if the `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` is configured in manifest