# Is there a way for a retained fragment to know when screen orientation has been changed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I want to run some code in my retained `Fragment` when the screen orientation changes.

I noticed the common solution for this is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13877507/1304252)

But that runs code on the initial setup of the `Fragment`. I don't want that. I only want code to run if a orientation change has occurred.

**EDIT:** it doesnt matter if I use `onAttach()`, `onActivityCreated()`, or `onCreate()`. I still have the same issue, which I explained because they are run on initial setup of the `Fragment`.

Comment: see updated answer. That is still what you want. `onCreate` in particular would have never worked because it is only called once when the Fragment is first created since it is retained. The other methods will work if you handle it properly and I added an example for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The life cycle for a retained fragment is different as I'm sure you noticed. `onCreate` of the retained fragment will not be called when the device is rotated.

Instead you can override either `onAttach` or `onActivityCreated` and check for orientation change as those are [still called](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)).

Here is an example to detect an orientation change:

```
private int currentOrientation = -1;

public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if(currentOrientation == -1) {
        //first time here set orientation
        currentOrientation = orientation;
    } else if(currentOrientation != orientation) {
        // orientation changed, execute custom code.
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt matter if I use onAttach, onActivityCreated, or onCreate. I still have the same issue, which I explained because they are run on initial setup of fragment.

Comment: So set a variable the first time the Fragment is created with the current orientation and only run your custom code if the orientation no longer matches what you saved the next time `onAttach` or `onActivityCreated` is called.

Comment: Yeah, just set it to some default that it can't be like `int orientation = Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  If it equals that, then you know it's never been set before which means the user has not rotated the device yet.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documents](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)), only `onCreate` and `onDestroy` will be omitted since the Fragment is not created or destroyed.  However, `onActivityCreated`, `onStart`, and `onAttach` are always called.  So you can move that code in to one of those methods.  It may also be good to keep track of the previous orientation change on the event that you remove your Fragment temporarily for whatever reason (since the lifecycles will be called on them for detaching from the Activity).